# Instagram API pagination: Storing returned data

Tags: javascript, api, rest, pagination, instagram

I've been tinkering around with pagination via the Instagram API; however, I'm a bit stuck as to how to go about storing returned data through my recursive calls.

I would like to store all of the item links in an array, but my current method returns an empty array.

```
var collected_objs = []; // Array to collect links (urls)

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fetch_followers').click(function() {
        pollInstagram('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?callback=?&min_timestamp=1388563200&max_timestamp=1420099200&access_token={access_token}', 33);
    });
});

function pollInstagram(next_url, count) {
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: next_url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
    success: function(data) {

        $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
            $("#log").val($("#log").val() + item.id + '\n');
            console.log("****************************");
            console.log("This " + JSON.stringify(item.link));
            console.log("****************************");
            $('#target').append('<div id="likes_info"><a href="'+item.link+'"><img src="'+item.images.thumbnail.url+'"/></a>'+"<p><span>"+item.likes.count+"</span></p></div>");

            collected_objs.push(item.link); // Adding urls to collected_objs -- Not Working
        });
        $("#log").val($("#log").val() + data.pagination.next_url + '\n');

        // If the next url is not null or blank:
        if( data.pagination.next_url && count <=50 ) {
            var n_url=data.pagination.next_url + "&callback=?";
            pollInstagram(n_url, ++count);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //alert("Check you internet Connection");
        $("#log").val($("#log").val() + 'Error\n');
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Define "not working". I don't see how you are actually using the results of `collected_objs`. Are you properly handling the asynchronous nature of your ajax request?

Comment: I mean to say that the variable collected_objs is not being updated after the calls have been made. This is my first working with asynchronous calls, which explains my ignorance in understanding how to keep the global variables updated after the pagination has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Because your ajax request to the instagram api executes asynchronously, you will need to either use a callback (passed in as an argument) or return a `$.Deferred`. I'd also suggest looking up resources on handling asynchronous javascript. It can be difficult to get your head around at first but there are *plenty* of tutorials out there.

The following is **untested** use at your own risk :)

**callback route**

```
  function pollInstagram(next_url, count, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      //  ** snip **
      success: function (data) {
        // ** add data to collected objs **

        // pass our transformed data to callback
        callback(collectedObjs);
      }
      //  ** snip **
    })
  }

  // usage:
  pollInstaGram('url', count, function (objs) {
    // this callback is executed _after_
    // the ajax request completes
    // and passed data
    // do something with objs
  });
```

**deferred route**

```
  function pollInstagram(next_url, count) {
    // we return a jQuery defferred
    return $.ajax({
    //  ** snip **
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      // add data to collectedObjs
      return collectedObjs;
    })
    .fail(function () {
      // handle failure case
    })
  }

  // usage
  pollInstaGram('url', count).done(function (objs) {
    // done is executed after the deferred is resolved
    // with the transformed values from our `.then`
    // ** do something with objs **
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @nicktomlin! I'll read into asynchronous javascript then test out the snippet. Will report back with my results.